# AWS Data Pipeline between RDS Instances (MySQL)

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

Is it possible to build a data pipeline in AWS to transfer data between two different RDS MySQL instances? The transfer would be taking place once per day (although not necessarily at the same time every day).

I am interested in copying full datatables from one instance to another, but the documentation for the data pipeline service doesn't seem to consider this use case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If one is a copy of the other, you can use Data Migration Services (a different Amazon service).

If you choose "ongoing replication" then the service will update your target database throughout the day with changes from the source database.

I suspect if you start making changes to the target database that make it different to the source database then you will have problems.